# select2 not displaying search results

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am trying to implement Remote Data Select2.

I am accessing data from api. The format is as follows:

```
concept_id,name
228,Pelecypoda
286,Pelecypoda
```

When I try to console data in results, it doesn't get consoled. But if I replace the word results with success, I can see the data in console but not in the search results.

**Script**

```
$("#search_text").select2({
      minimumInputLength: 3,
      ajax: {
          url: "http://192.241.245.176:4567/api1",
          dataType: 'text',
          type: "GET",
          quietMillis: 250,
          data: function (term) { 
              console.log(term)
              return {
                    q: term.term //search term
              }
           },
           results: function (data,page) {
              console.log(data,"-----RESULTS-----");
              return d3.csv.parse(data, function (d) {
                  console.log(d);
                  return {results: d.name}
               });
            },
            dropdownCssClass: "bigdrop"
});
```

Can anyone please tell me where am I going wrong? Do I have to specify formatResults and formatSelection provided by select2?

Comment: The problem should be on your url parameter. Is api on a different server than you're running the script?

Comment: Yes. The api is on different server. Can you please tell me the way around it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489373/how-to-use-jquery-ajax-for-an-outside-domain

Comment: I don't think so the problem is that I am accessing api on different server, because even when I try to save json data in my local system, it doesnt show up the results.

Comment: What version of Select2 are you using? Because with the new v4.0, the "results" function was renamed to "processResults".

Comment: @JohnS I am using select2 version 3.5.2