# JSON object is null, even though feed is valid JSON

Tags: json, jquery, jsonp

Help, I'm confused.
I just need to get a JSON object into my page. The URL is as follows:

```
http://disqus.com/api/get_forum_posts/?user_api_key=MYKEY&forum_id=MYID&api_version=1.1
```

If I use the Flickr API URL and the code given in the [getJSON example](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), it works fine:

```
<script>$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?",
        function(data){
          alert(data);
          $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
            $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images");
            if ( i == 3 ) return false;
          });
        });</script>
```

But, if I substitute in the Disqus URL above, the data is null. After reading [JSON Feed Returning null while using jQuery getJSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429834/json-feed-returning-null-while-using-jquery-getjson) I checked whether this URL returned valid JSON, and it does.

The [Disqus API](http://wiki.disqus.net/API) seems to suggest it supports JSONP - 'You can also pass "jsonp:callback" as the "api_response_format" parameter'. I've tried adding this parameter, but it doesn't help.

What am I doing wrong? I suspect the problem may be that I don't really understand the difference between JSON and JSONP, and what I need to be doing to get JSONP back.

Comment: Why exactly do you think that the object is null? This should work correctly, except you're trying to iterate over `data.items` property, which is not present in Disqus's response. Could that be the source of the problem?

Comment: Because the alert(data) brings an alert up saying 'null'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call it like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://disqus.com/api/get_forum_posts/?user_api_key=MYKEY&forum_id=MYID&api_version=1.1&api_response_format=jsonp:myFunction',
  dataType:  'jsonp'
});
function myFunction(data) { //make sure this is available globally
  //use data
}
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/47Z3u/).

Like your documentation link, the parameter on the end `api_response_format=jsonp:myFunction` is the key, check the link directly [here](http://disqus.com/api/get_forum_posts/?user_api_key=MYKEY&forum_id=MYID&api_version=1.1&api_response_format=jsonp:myFunction), even though it's an error because of the key, see how for format is different?  That's what's required for a JSONP call, the `functionName({data})` response format.

Answer (score 0):

Copying the two URL's provided by yourself into a browser window, the DISQUS URL returns with an error, "Problem loading page".

Comment: Well one problem would be that `MYKEY` is not a valid Disqus API key.

Answer (score 0):

The Disqus call is missing a callback function

Answer (score 0):

The `api_response_format=jsonp:callback` argument is supposed to be the name of a callback function defined in by your Javascript. So let's say I have a function called `handleJson` which is supposed to parse a JSON response, then you have to pass the argument `jsonp:handleJson`. Disqus will then pass you code wrapped in a call to `handleJson`.

What JSONP brings is the ability to get around the same-domain origin policy. Suppose that a URL <`http://foo/json`> responds with this JSON object:

```
{
  id: 2,
  first_name: 'John',
  last_name: 'Doe',
}
```

The only way you could use that object is if you are also on domain foo. But if you are not able to be on that domain, suppose that you are accessing an API that returns JSON format objects, then you ned a little help from that API provider.

Suppose that the url you request now becomes <`http://foo/json?callback=handleJson`> and the API provider responds with this:

```
handleJson({id: 2, first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Doe'})
```

Now, the browser is going to try to run that snippet of Javascript inside of the environment you've defined. So if you've defined a `handleJson` function, it's going to be called.

That's what JSONP is, a way to circumvent the same-domain origin policy and give you cross-site scripting with JSON objects.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if your dates aren't padded with zeros, then the events won't show. 
Ex. 2010-9-5 bad
Ex. 2010-09-05 good