# Can't get HTML page from other site with jQuery ($.get, $.ajax)

Tags: jquery, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [load content from external page into another page using ajax/query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560183/load-content-from-external-page-into-another-page-using-ajax-query)

May be I just don't get something.

I want to get html page from other site, let it be http://www.server.com/somepage/param

In my js code:

```
  var url = "http://www.server.com/somepage/param";
   $.get(url, callback);
```

Chrome says "Failed to load resource".

What is wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're running into restrictions imposed by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). In short, AJAX calls to a different domain are prohibited and will always fail.

You need to either use JSONP (mostly applicable to data returned by APIs) or [proxy the request through your own server/domain](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html).

Comment: Well, but I've got a chrome extension, and it makes such requests, and get the information from site I need. How? I looked at js source it uses jQuery.

Comment: It uses special permissions given to Plugins. Here's an excellent writeup about how to implement this: http://www.sarajchipps.com/2011/01/using-jquery-ajax-calls-in-a-chrome-plugin.html

Comment: Oh, thank you very much for your answer. Sadly that, this simple solution works only in crhome, It seems that I need to find a way to use proxy solution with my ROR 3.1 server

Comment: But what about this document: http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/ (infromation from here http://merbist.com/2011/09/14/how-to-cross-domain-ajax-in-a-ruby-app/ - However, most browsers (IE 8+, Firefox 3.5+, Safari 4+, Chrome) implement a simple way to allow cross domain requests as defined in this w3C document.)

Comment: Well, can you get the remote host to send a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://yourhost.com` header?

Comment: Oh, I believe no =( so the only way it make proxy on my server?

Comment: Yap. Shouldn't be too complicated though, should it? In PHP, that'd be a three-liner.

Answer (score 6):

The simple answer is, no, this is not possible. Cross Domain AJAX is not allowed. However, you can find a (working) workaround here:

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html

More details about cross-domain ajax requests: [Dashboard Cross-domain AJAX with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570100/dashboard-cross-domain-ajax-with-jquery/570225#570225)

Comment: Well, but I've got a chrome extension, and it makes such requests, and get the information from site I need. How? I looked at js source it uses jQuery.