# Read div value from webpage

Tags: javascript

I haven't really found anything about this. I want to read data from a website. From my webpage I can read a div's value with

```
<div class="tools">hammer</div>

var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for(var i=0; i<divs.length; i++ ) {
        if(divs[i].className == "tools") {
            alert(divs[i].innerHTML);
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to set the URL of the desired webpage so this code would scrape that page? I know the classname and the url.

Based on @cereallarceny's answer I created this code block but I see no alert when running the script:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'get',
url: 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.viber.voip',
crossDomain: true, //Very important, ensures you can get data from a domain that isn't your own!
success: function() {
  var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for(var i=0; i<divs.length; i++ ) {
        if(divs[i].className == "votes") {
            alert(divs[i].innerHTML);
        }
    }
}
});
```

Comment: You could use `getElementsByClassName` instead of `getElementsByTagName` to get all elements with `class="tools"`.

Comment: Does it have to be with javascript? you can use a bash script, or java with HttpSocket

Comment: @Pietu1998 AFAIK getElementsByClassName  is not supported by all browsers or it has issues sometimes

Comment: @MitchBukaner I know js and php. What do you have in mind?

Comment: it is to look for something from other website, right?

Comment: Yes it is. In this case I need the value of tools which is hammer.

Comment: I mean... what's wrong with AJAX?  That seems a bit more progressive in my opinion.

Comment: @erdomester Well, according to W3Schools "getElementsByClassName() does not work in Internet Explorer 5,6,7, and 8."

Comment: Why don't we just use Sizzle: `$(".tools");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using a library like jQuery then you could simply use the `load()` function which gets the code of a webpage (or a partial of a webpage if you append a `#myDiv` to the URL).  You could then handle that information if you put it in a variable.  If you're just using Javascript then you'd need to look into making an AJAX request (which is what `load()` does).  You can find more information on how to do this [located here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197709/javascript-read-html-from-url-into-string).

For more information on the `load()` function, [read jQuery's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Keep in mind, jQuery's `load()` function is for loading HTML into an element.  If you want to read and manipulate that data then you should probably use the [`ajax()` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).  This way you could do something like the following:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'http://www.google.com',
    crossDomain: true, //Very important, ensures you can get data from a domain that isn't your own!
    success: function(data) {
        $('#myDiv').html(data);

        //Now I can handle all the HTML from my URL from a <div> tag called #myDiv, the following will alert out the body of http://www.google.com
        alert($('#myDiv').find('body'));
    }
});
```

This will essentially make a **GET** request to the specified URL, while noting that it is not of the same domain name as the request's origin (your server) and then handles the success in a function with the HTML returned in a variable `data`.  You can use data however you please now seeing as it's your variable now, including parsing of that information how you please.

Comment: No @jgillich... that's the load **event** in jQuery.  I'm talking about the load function.  http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: This looks good. Should I put my code into the function? I mean ` success: function(data) {  my whole js code }`

Comment: mmm this answer is probably better than mine

Comment: You could put the code in there but I doubt it'd work without some jimmyrigging.  :)  My code uses jQuery (http://jquery.com), if you're going to use any jQuery then you might as well have your code be jQuery as well, which it isn't.  This way you stick to conformity within your code.

Comment: I just added that code block to my question. I have jquery else in the code so the necessary jquery version is imported in the file. What else do I need?

Comment: Check my edited response... it should better suit your needs.  This way you can work with the HTML using jQuery and not via parsing a string on your own.  You need to include the jQuery library in your source code if you haven't.  Read this article on how to set up jQuery: http://www.jquery4u.com/tutorials/setup-jquery/

Comment: Was I able to help you @erdomester?

Comment: You were of great help but it turned out I didn't javascript as I managed to do it from Android (I thought I need to run a js script) by reading the whole page and looking for the div value. The load() function looked Chinese to me. If you could provide me with a full code I would be grateful, because I may need this later.

Comment: Sounds good to me man!  So long as you got the right solution, that's all that matters, right?  Thanks for the answer accept!

Comment: I'm sorry I would never ask for this, but like I said I couldn't use load(). The ajax code you provided didn't return anything

Comment: Load would work like such: `$("#myDiv").load("http://www.google.com");`. However, I'm not sure this would work because of Javascript requiring loads to be done on the same domain... hence why it wouldn't return anything. Check your developer console for any Javascript errors, that should do some explaining as to why you didn't get a return.

Answer (score 0):

```
$file=fopen($URL,'r'); 
    if ($file) 
    { 
    $string =""; 
    while (!feof($file)){ 
            $string .=fgets($file,512); 
    } 
echo $string; 
}else echo "error";
```

this echoes the web. but you can do with it what ever.

Ok. here is a how to ask for a webSite in js

```
var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }


   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    return xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }


var answerFromURL=xmlhttp.onreadystatechange();


    xmlhttp.open("GET","urlToParse.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: This is not even JavaScript.

Comment: it is php. He said he knew

Comment: I know it's php, but the question specifically ask for a JavaScript solution. (The tag...)

Comment: You have to look for the subString with that tag, then the end tag, and save the content.