# Is there any way to convert svg url to <svg> tag in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I’ve been looking for the solution to convert or extract the svg from a url link svg file to html as original  from the link.

e.g.

https://server/soccerball.svg (image url from server that has svg components inside with its paths etc.)

I would like to get the  element from inside the link following with its paths and attributes on every elements from the link above in JavaScript. It can be in a form of actual element/string it wont matter.

For example from the link above converted to:

<svg attr…>…

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add an `<img>` element with `src="https://server/soccerball.svg"` attribute?

Comment: Use `fetch` as indicated on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67611415/3695983). That way you'll read the SVG as a string and you can put it on the page or process it however you want.

Comment: Better answer using ``fetch``: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69801088/load-an-svg-image-where-the-elements-become-part-of-the-dom