# javascript jquery , load , post

Tags: jquery

Why when i use JQuery `.load` or `.post` with something not in my local
for example

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("body").load("http://google.com");
});
```

it doesn't load.
Same thing with `.post`.
Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: Load makes an AJAX request and those can NEVER be between two different domains. (except JSON, but thats is different)

Comment: I'm sure this is not the first time this has been asked, look around before asking please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't get HTML page from other site with jQuery ($.get, $.ajax)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629905/cant-get-html-page-from-other-site-with-jquery-get-ajax)

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is blocked by anti-cross-site scripting measures from within the browser. This has also been asked several times on SO, I'd suggest you look for one of the answers. My understanding is there is a hack to enable XSS(cross site scripting) from the localhost in Firefox only.

Answer (score 0):

You're running into restrictions imposed by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). In short, AJAX calls to a different domain are prohibited and will always fail.

You need to either use JSONP (mostly applicable to data returned by APIs) or [proxy the request through your own server/domain](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html).

Comment: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html
 this example is good but do you got any idea how to post and else if that link got things loaded by jquery its cant load it right ?

Comment: anyway thanks i helped my self i found a way to send it by JavaScript is self :)

Answer (score 0):

> Description: Load data from the server and place the returned HTML
>   into the matched element.

This method is the simplest way to fetch data from the server.

please read http://api.jquery.com/load/

it is clearly said that from `load()` you can fetch data from `your server` . you can not access data in a different domain  .

Comment: oh sorry , i ll take a look .